# Capturing exact amount of numbers without Whitespaces

Tags: regex

I have a series of 8-digit-numbers that I need to capture via RegEx. 
Single whitespaces can occur before, after and in some cases between the digits. In some cases, other chars follow. Here's the most common variations, each of which I want to capture as `12345678`:

```
123456789
 12345678
1234567 89S
12345 678 9
123 456789
123456 789
```

Is this possible?

Comment: can´t you replace non numeric numbers by an empty string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible in a single "regex" step. I can go into more detail if you like, but basically regex cannot "count" (it can only match a specified match size, such as "8 numbers", but not "an unknown number of characters, 8 of which are numbers").

You need to do this in two stages -

- first remove whitespace.
- then perform a regex match.

For instance, in ruby:

```
thingtomatch = "  12 3456  7899X"
temp = thingtomatch.squeeze(' ').strip  # => temp="1234567899X"
matched_digits = temp.match(/(\d{8}).*/)[1]
```

(Or, as other answers have suggested, you could perform a regex match and then remove whitespace from the result.)

Comment: Here is a link showing your "working" regex: http://www.rubular.com/r/dERll4GyOR ... as you can see, it does not work.

Comment: Even if you were to "fix" it by replacing the "?" with a "*", you'd still need a second step to remove whitespace from the match!! (Which is pretty much exactly what I did - I just did the whitespace removal before, rather than after.)

Comment: I don't want to wade into your particular back and forth, but I keep pondering the use of the word `Single` in the question. If the requirement is to **only** allow 0 or 1 whitespace then `?` is correct, and "strip then match" is going to struggle vs "match then strip".

Comment: Ah yes, good spot - I hadn't noticed that. But still, my point stands that a single regex step is not possible, and a second "strip" is needed either before or after. However, in terms of runtime speed, I highly doubt doing strip-then-match or match-then-strip is going to have any significant impact!

Comment: ahhh..i took a look at the question again and realized my mistake..+1 for your ans

Answer (score 3):

I think a regex like:

```
(( )?\d){8}
```

Would suffice to capture the digits - I'd then remove the whitespace (before further processing) as a separate step.

---

I'm not sure how strictly to interpret the OP's "single whitespaces" requirement, but it's why I've structured my RegEx to accept 8 digits, each of which is optionally prefixed by a single space character.

If it should only match if there are single spaces, and not any more, the above works whereas the "strip whitespace first" or "strip non-digits first" approaches will not.

If more spaces are allowed, it's easy to change the `?` to a `*` or any fixed upper limit.

Comment: this will match, but I won't be able to capture this way. I guess I will have to strip out the whitespaces before and then try the expression.

Comment: @SebastianEdelmeier - as you may notice a theme running through all of the answers, yes, you have to do it as two steps. Whether you strip the whitespaces *before* or *after* is really a matter of taste.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but in two steps:

First, remove non-digits:

```
s/[^\d]//g
```

Second, match your digits:

```
m/^(\d{8})$/
```

Comment: That will not match `12345678` in `123456789`. First example in the question.

Comment: ...Which could easily be fixed by removing the "$".

Comment: However, your answer WILL match something like "1234ABCD5678", since you are removing all non-digit characters. Which is wrong.